# Which file converter do I write for education, fun and real-world application?

Tags: binaryfiles

I am looking for some real-world application task which singlehandedly will give me some programming experience. I am thinking about file format converter but I am not sure about which pair of formats to chose. I would prefer a binary or mixed formats as more trickier ones. Which of existing file format conversion would you suggest to me to look at ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

BMP - TGA image file conversion is an appropriate start. This also allows you to add more formats as you progress.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. But I see a lot of converters doing that already. So it's kind of "academic". I am looking for something that may be found useful by others. So if I am not payed for this - somebody will save his/her time or even earn some money :). Even if format is rare and not fully documented - it is fine by me. Reverse engineering trains brain even better. ;)

Regards

Comment: @opal: ok, I think I understand better now - I was under the impression that you mainly wanted to learn for yourself.

Comment: Ok, let's rephrase the question a little bit: "Which file converting software were you looking for recently but didn't manage to find" ?

Answer (score 1):

A converter from `.fsdb` to `.ltx`, `.ltx2`, `.fst` and the other way around ( `.ltx`, `.ltx2`, `.fst` to `.fsdb` ) would be very very nice to have.

The `.ltx`, `.ltx2`, `.fst` are formats used and understood by **gtkwave** waveform viewer. The [`gtkwave`](http://gtkwave.sourceforge.net/) is very capable open source waveform viewer used in digital/mixed signal design community.

The `.fsdb` is the proprietary format used in the commercial waveform viewer [**verdi**](http://www.springsoft.com/products/debug-automation/verdi/) (former 'debussy').